# jQuery mobile middle vertical align for li in listview

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, center

How to center text vertically in a list view item?

For example, running this code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="exerciseList">    
<li>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/0/02/Homer_Simpson_2006.png">
    <p>Some large text 
    Some large text 
    Some large text 
    Some large text 
    Some large text 
    Some large text</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

I get this:

[image]

but I need this:

[image]

Comment: try using flex layout. using flexbox layout display, you can arrange vertically and horizontally layout elements inside container. This link could be useful https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I visited the link provided, but didn't know what to do with the information, can somebody please provide a more direct solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done easily with flex boxes. I took your code and created a  [code pen](http://codepen.io/ravishtiwari/pen/QjGEPX), I took liberty of adding a few elements here and there, for example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide-show">
  <ul data-role="listview" id="exerciseList">
    <li>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/0/02/Homer_Simpson_2006.png">
      </div>
      <div class="detail">
        Some large text Some large text Some large text Some large text Some large text Some large text
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and **CSS**

```
.slide-show {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}
.slide-show ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#exerciseList li {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#exerciseList li .image {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#exerciseList li .image img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Have a look at the [code pen](http://codepen.io/ravishtiwari/pen/QjGEPX) and see for your self, you can use the link provided above to customize it for your self

Comment: The sample provided looks great, however, when I try to apply the CSS to a jQuery mobile listview I can't get the expected result. How can I apply the same idea to a jQuery mobile listview?

Comment: I have never used jQuery Mobile, so can't tell much about it. However, I did find this thread on it's forum https://forum.jquery.com/topic/tabular-listviews-using-the-flexbox-model this has no answer, but, seems like he is trying to do what you want to. I believe you will need to tweak the result a bit depending upon your html structure and the CSS you have.